# Membership.ValidateUser access SQLMembershipProvider instead my Custom membership Provider

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, membership-provider, custom-membershipprovider

I created a custom membership provider (empty yet, only the ValidateUser method has code).

```
    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

lol.

And my web.config has this tag:

```
<membership defaultProvider="LigaeDesligaMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CoolMembershipProvider"
         type="CoolProject.Web.Memberships.CoolMembershipProvider, CoolProject.Web"
         enablePasswordReset="true"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

But when I call this:

```
  if (Membership.ValidateUser(username, password))
  {
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, persistcookies);
      return true;
  }
```

I got an error
"Can not connect to the database from SQL Server."

The application doesnt hit the breakpoint inside my custom Membership and I guess is using another membership.

I'm using MVC5 and EF6.

Please, tell me too if I'm wrong in my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My web.config was wrong.
Following the blog post I make it correctly.

http://logcorner.wordpress.com/2013/08/29/how-to-configure-custom-membership-and-role-provider-using-asp-net-mvc4/